# Can I return a List from a LotusScript Function?

Tags: return-value, lotus-notes, lotusscript

I want to return a List from a Function in LotusScript.

eg.

```
Function myfunc() List As Variant
    Dim mylist List As Variant
    mylist("one") = 1
    mylist("two") = "2"
    myfunc = mylist
End Function

Dim mylist List As Variant
mylist = myfunc()
```

Is this possible?

If so, what is the correct syntax?

Comment: This is one example of how Lotus Notes/Domino kills you with a thousand paper cuts....

Answer (score 8):

It seems you can't return a List from a Function.

You can easily wrap it in a class though and return the class.

eg.

```
Class WrappedList
    Public list List As Variant
End Class

Function myfunc() As WrappedList
    Dim mylist As New WrappedList
    mylist.list("one") = 1
    mylist.list("two") = "2"
    Set myfunc = mylist
End Function
```

Answer was found here: [LotusScript's List bug strikes again](http://dominounlimited.blogspot.com/2008/06/lotusscripts-list-bug-strikes-again.html?showComment=1212495540000#c8995286986513838505)

Comment: Good answer! +1 but.. Ugh, I hate variants! You could define the class as having Public list List As NotesDocument (for example - could be any class / type) . That way when you do a foreach x in wrappedList.list .. End For, on the list, the index variable will have a type. Otherwise if you leave it as variant, you vget no typeahead from Notes Designer because it's a variant

Answer (score 2):

This works fine for me. I've set one value to string and the other to integer so you can see that the variants behave themselves.

```
Sub Initialize
    Dim mylist List As Variant
    Call myfunc(mylist)
    Msgbox "un  = " + mylist("one")
    Msgbox "deux = " + cstr(mylist("two"))
End Sub

Sub myfunc(mylist List As Variant)
    mylist("one") = "1"
    mylist("two") = 2
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get a function toi return a list, just get rid of "List" bit in your function, so instead of

```
Function myfunc() List As Variant
   ...
End Function
```

...do:

```
Function myfunc() As Variant
```

then you can call your function as you already do.

```
Dim mylist List As Variant
mylist = myfunc()
```

Lists are great and I use them all the time, but I have found one limitation with lists...

if if have a function like:

```
Public Function returnMyList() as Variant

   Dim myList List as Variant
   Dim s_test as String
   Dim i as Integer
   Dim doc as NotesDocuemnt
   Dim anotherList List as String

   '// ...set your variables however you like

   myList( "Some Text" ) = s_text
   myList( "Some Integer" ) = i
   myList( "Some Doc" ) = doc

   '// If you returned the list here, you're fine, but if you add
   '// another list...
   anotherList( "one" ) = ""
   anotherList( "two" ) = ""
   myList( "Another List" ) = anotherList

   '//  This will cause an error
   returnMyList = myList

   '// I bodge around this by writting directly to a List 
   '// that is set as global variable.

End Function
```

Comment: The root of the problem when having a List contained in a List is that the Variant type cannot hold this kind of object. It might come as a surprise that a Variant can't hold a certain type, but this limitation has literally cost me hundreds of hours once..

Answer (score 1):

Simply put you gotta have a function that returns a variant. I can see that you like to do it in an object oriented fashion, but if you just want to "get it done" procedurally is the easiest.

Although there are a couple of ways to do this, this is my preferred way. Note that you can create a list of any primitive data type, (ie string, variant, integer, long etc).

```
Function myfunc as variant
    dim mylist list as variant
    mylist("somename") = "the value you want to store"
    mylist("someothername") = "another value"
    myfunc = mylist

End Function
```

To use myfunc ..

```
sub initialise
    dim anotherlist list as variant
    anotherlist = myfunc
end sub
```

You can add parameters to myfunc if you need to by simply defining myfunc this way

```
function myfunc(val1 as variant, val2 as variant) as variant
```

You call it the same ways with parameters like this

```
anotherlist = myfunc("a value", "another value")
```

Note that "variant" is your universal datatype. What's important is that myfunc as a variant is the only way you can return lists and variants from a function.