# Return List from Lotusscript webservice

Tags: web-services, lotus-notes, lotusscript

I have  webservice on Lotusscript, and I want some function to return a list of elements.

As I know,  Lotusscript functions can't return Lists of objects, you need to create a wrapper class to return lists ([Can I return a List from a LotusScript Function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593533/can-i-return-a-list-from-a-lotusscript-function))

Here is the 1st version of code:

```
Class myClass   
Public Function getList As Person
    Dim pers As New Person      
    pers.info = "Iron Man"      
    Set getList = pers      
End Function    
End Class

Class Person
Public info As String   
End Class
```

PortType class is set to myClass. This code works quite well and returns one object of class Person.

But when I try to return List of objects:

```
Class myClass   
Public Function getList As PersonLst
    Dim pers As New Person 
    Dim persLst As New PersonLst 
    pers.info = "Iron Man"
    Set persLst.lst("Tony Stark") = pers                
    Set getList = persLst       
End Function    
End Class

Class Person
Public info As String   
End Class

Class PersonLst
Public lst List As Person
End Class
```

I have the following error when i save my webservice:

```
The Web Service has been saved, but is not valid: Please specify which 
class exposes your web service interface(s), using the 
'PortType class' field of the Web Service properties panel
```

although PortType is still set to myClass.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a lotus script array as these will map to SOAP types. 
See [Web Service Mapping](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_WEB_SERVICES_WEB_MAPPINGS.html) which explains how arrays are mapped, and special cases for different versions of Domino and empty arrays.